# Verify using Moq that only these two method calls where called, and nothing else

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, tdd, moq

I am using Moq for verifications and unit-testing.  I would like to verify that say a method 'Add' was called with parameter 1, and parameter 5, and **not called** for any other value except for those.

Is it possible to create verifications, something similar to the code below? (note this is not actual code!)

```
mock.Verify(x=>x.Add(1), Times.Once());
mock.Verify(x=>x.Add(5), Times.Once());
mock.Verify(x=>x.Add(It.IsAny<int>()), Times.Never());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this, passing a lambda expression to the third verification to exclude any value different from 1 and 5.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using Moq;

namespace Tests.x21
{
    public interface IMyInterface
    {
        void Add(int num);
    }

    public class Executor
    {
        private IMyInterface _dep;

        public Executor(IMyInterface dep)
        {
            _dep = dep;
        }

        public void Execute()
        {
            _dep.Add(1);
            _dep.Add(5);
            _dep.Add(4);    // comment to make the test work
        }
    }

    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest21
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {
            var mock = new Mock<IMyInterface>();
            var executor = new Executor(mock.Object);
            executor.Execute();
            mock.Verify(x => x.Add(1), Times.Once());
            mock.Verify(x => x.Add(5), Times.Once());
            mock.Verify(m => m.Add(It.Is<int>(num => num != 1 && num != 5)), Times.Never());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, that would work.  A workaround I have done is that if I only want those 2 instances, then obviously there shouldn't be any other calls.  Right after the assertions, I did `mock.Verify(x => x.Add(It.IsAny<int>(), Times.Exactly(2)))`.  This way, if it is called for any other value, it won't be just two.  Avoids having to write all the combination duplicates in my opinion.

Comment: Yes, that's a good approach! Anyway, I'd like to point out how lambda expressions can be used to validate the values passed to the mock object.